# Git: a tracked file was not pushed to gitlab server

Tags: git, gitlab

Git track my `__init__.py` file. I was sure of it by following command

```
git ls-files --error-unmatch __init__.py
```

but when I push my code to the my gitlab server, it was not pushed. why?

Comment: Please share outputs

Comment: Git does not push files. Git pushes *commits*. A *tracked file* is by definition one that is in Git's index. Is it also in a *commit*, and did you push that commit? If so, find *that commit* in the Git repository on the GItLab server, and you'll find your file therein. Is that commit *checked out* on the GitLab server? If not, why do you think the file "was not pushed"?

Comment: Note that Git will build a new commit that you make now from whatever is in Git's index now. But: if you just now add a file to Git's index, to make it tracked, but don't *commit*, it's not yet in any *commit*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my local when use ls command, i see __init__.py file but in git lab server when go to that directory. __init__.py dose not exist. There is nothing for commit and also push into server and my branch is up to date.